# Store data from several classes in central object

Tags: android, save, singleton

I have an app that relies heavily on JSON responses from a webservice. All parts of the app contain objects build from these responses meaning this data is very important for the app to run properly.

Currently, every time a function of the app gets opened by the user (for example news, music, pictures, et cetera), the webservice gets queried and responds with the desired data. This data then gets parsed and used to show the user whatever it is they chose.
The problem is, this process is very bandwidth unfriendly. Especially for phones with slower connections it might take a few seconds to load and parse the data, let alone download the pictures that will be shown.
If a users closes the function, and then opens it again, all data gets re-downloaded and re-parsed.

Therefore, I want to save the most commonly used data in a central class / object. Since this data is unlikely to change while the user is using the app, it should be possible to save the required data somewhere in case the user reopens a function they just closed.

But how would I do such a thing? I read about Singletons and such, but how would I add data to a Singleton object from over 20 different classes? And how would I retrieve this data and add it to a new Intent for when the user re-opens a function (if this is even possible at all)

Comment: use SQLite (db) and contentprovider ... here is an example: http://esilo.pl/selvin/LooserSample.zip it do sync on start or if you force sync using menu->sync in main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion but not necessarily the best way, I am not sure if I have interpreted your question correctly.

Would you be able to store any of it in an sql lite db or maybe on the sd card?

For the music and images you could store the path to the item on the sd card in the DB.

Then update the db each time the data changes either each time the app loads or by calling an "has the data changed" link?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have made my current situation clearer, but I'll sketch out one of the problems for you.

Right now, the app contains an option to show a list of albums from a particular band. These albums all have an album cover, a title, info about the album and all that. All this data gets loaded every time the user selects a band. Now saving all this data wouldn't be such a problem, but the user can change which band they want to check out. Meaning that if I would save all data in a database, this database might grow out of proportions quite quickly

Comment: The music itself doesn't have to be saved, since that get's streamed anyway (besides, saving several dozens of MP3 files of 4MB or bigger might be a bit of a hassle).
I'd just like to save the pictures of the band if possible for now. Would it be possible to save those to the SD card / database, and like you said, while the app loads check if the data has changed?

Comment: The sqlite may be a bit overkill for just storing one option but it would work. Sqllite will store it even when the app is closed so it will persist for the next time the user opens it. I suppose you'd have a unique reference for that band and a version num then call a website for a true/false of whether the dat has changed.. then update it all if it has.
Then when the user chooses a different band just delete all the stored data and add the new stuff.

Comment: Another thought you may be able to save it in sharedpreferences and still have a link to the sd card, it would save sorting out a sql lite db?
This is me thinking out loud as I'm not entirely sure if this saves when the app closes.. check out this link though: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref  There's a few data storage options. (just checked it does store even after the app is closed)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I'll look into the SQLite area then. 
Sadly I can't use your suggestion for the true/false check using a website/the webservice since I'm working on this for an internship project, and I can't physically change the webservice / request a change in the webservices.
However, since I can still receive the JSON responses after saving data in the database, I'm guessing I could check whether the mediaID in the DB (You can save an image and some data as one record right, like in a normal SQL database?) equals the one in the response. Hmm. Interesting stuff, thanks!

Comment: Edit: Oh wait nevermind, I get what you mean.  Save the actual image on the SD card, and save a record of where it saved in the SharedPrefs. Hmm. That might work too.  I'll try both and see which works best for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem in my games with highscores -  highscore lists are big and  come as JSON from HTTP Get requests.  I use:
  - singleton highscore service which is responsible for caching local JSON copy, handles retrieval from HTTP etc.   Since loadfing higscores taks time,  it also performs asynchronous processing and fires broadcasts when new highscores are available ( and game activities receive them if they need it)
  - broadcast receivers for timed broadacasts to perform regular higscore synchtronisation

I use my own databinding library for JSON data storage:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer